# After changing permission of ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and the ~/.ssh directory I get a permission denied (public key)

Tags: server, permissions, ssh

Without changing the permissions this error doesn't occur. I'm changing them with:

```
sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(same steps as in this [answer](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/413/i-get-the-error-permission-denied-publickey-when-i-connect-with-ssh))

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`? are the files owned by `root`?

Comment: @steeldriver
Thanks for the reply
It tells me permission denied if I don't use sudo.
The authorized_keys is owned by root 
`rw------- 1 root root 744 Aug 11 10:34 authorized_keys`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems are that the keys are owned by root.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.ssh
chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh
```

These two commands will restore ownership to user and set permissions appropriately.

The general rule is that everything in your home directory should be owned by you. In the case of ssh keys, ssh will refuse to work if ownership does not match username, as it may be a security problem.

Comment: I changed the permissions back with chown after steeldriver asked if they were owned by root and it still didn't work. Turned out that Digital Oceans console doesn't do well with copy pasting - it bummed my key up when I pasted it

Answer (score 0):

In my case the answer was that the console provided by Digital Ocean bummed up my key when I pasted it in. (I don't know why it does that but long strings get scrambled when you paste them).

So the solution for me was to download the key file with `curl`.